# More elegant ps aux | grep [g]rep do not work

Tags: linux, bash, regex, grep, ps

I am running the command: `ps -ef | grep [p]ts/1`

The result is:

`root     13820  1733  0 14:19 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/1
 root     13822 13820  0 14:19 pts/1    00:00:00 -bash
 root     15847 13822  0 15:32 pts/1    00:00:00 ps -ef
 root     15848 13822  0 15:32 pts/1    00:00:00 grep [p]ts/1`

Why is it returning `grep` and `ps`?

P.S. Single and double quotes give me the same results. I am able get output without "grep" using `grep -v grep` works, but I want to use more elegant way.

Comment: Why wouldn't it return them? They're processes, and they match your grep.

Comment: Don't we have `pgrep` these days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` just shows lines matching the regular expression you give it.

Each of the output lines you show does actually have the text "pts/1" on it, perhaps just not where you expected it to be, namely in the controlling tty column on those "unexpected" lines.

As thrig's comment says, you're probably better off with `pgrep`.

Comment: This really should work as the OP expects and generally does https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results

Answer (score 0):

The reason you see the **grep** and **ps -ef** processes in the output is because the grep command itself matches the pattern you provided, **[p]ts/1**.

The square brackets **[p]** in the pattern are a way to prevent grep from matching its own process in the output.
Let me break down the pattern **[p]ts/1**:

So when you run **ps -ef | grep [p]ts/1**, the **grep** process itself matches the pattern [p]ts/1, and you see it in the output.

One way to avoid this is to use the **-E** option with **grep** to enable extended regular expressions and then modify your pattern:

```
ps -ef | grep -E 'pts/1$'

root     13820  1733  0 14:19 ?        00:00:00 sshd: root@pts/1
```

With this approach, you won't need to use the square brackets to prevent grep from matching itself, and you should only see the relevant lines in the output.